# What brings you here? What has brought you here?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

Why do we ask people "What brings you here?" instead of "What has brought you here?"
According to Oxford Dictionary, "bring" here means "cause someone to come to a place." The cause of the visit happened before someone's coming. Therefore, isn't the usage of the present perfect more grammatical, as in "What has caused you to come here?"

Comment: *"What brings this question up?"*

Comment: I never hear either phrase unless reading a book or watching an old movie.

Comment: I hear "What brings you here" all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a hubby pet peeve and is SO frequently used here in the US.  While you're correct that "What has brought you here?" is correct, "What brings you here?" is generally understood to mean something very specific:

> **"Why are you here?"** or **"What has caused you to come here?"**, not what literally brought you (a car, a bus, a cab, a rickshaw).

The other part of that phrase that bothers non-native speakers is that **"brings"** is in the present tense and is anachronistic in the sense that if you are "here", you've been brought already and are not in the process of having something bring you.

Again, though odd and anachronistic, it is idiomatic to mean **"Why are you here?"** *Edit:* ...but in a less direct or confrontational way, as @Oldcat has kindly pointed out to me.

Comment: "Why are you here?" is a bit more confrontational, as if you really should be somewhere else.

Comment: I agree, @Oldcat, but that is what someone is asking, though in a softer way, when they say "What brings you here?".  I think that it's usually in a case where someone needs help or has made an appointment and the person helping them says, "What brings you here?" instead of "What is the purpose of your visit today?" or "Why have you come here today?".

Comment: I agree that the meaning is the same, just this form is used to defuse the original.  It is similar to how the server in a restaurant says "May I take your Order" rather than "What do you want?"

Comment: There's no difference in meaning or correctness; both are equally correct. This is talk, remember, not writing. There are some differences, but not many: _brings_ brings more present focus, while _has brought_ seems more formal, and certainly using any unnecessary auxiliaries in what is essentially meaningless small talk is more a mark of sociocultural status than anything else. As W.S. Gilbert put it, "This particularly rapid unintelligible patter isn't generally heard, and if it is it doesn't matter."

Comment: @JohnLawler - We were taught as medical students to ask open-ended questions, i.e. *What brings you here today* ("Why are you here" being too confrontational.) In PA, the answer is almost always *The ambulance* or *My son*. I have taken to asking differently.

Answer (score 1):

"What brings you here?" suggest that this isn't your first visit, indeed, you keep coming back, and why would you keep coming back?

"What has brought you here?" asks why did you come here in the first place?  It might not be the reason you are here now, but *something* brought you here in the beginning.  If this isn't it.

Comment: Actually, "What brings you here?" might well mean, "You never come here, so why are you here now?" It's a bit like the slightly ironic "To what do we owe the pleasure of your company today?"

Answer (score 0):

I think "brings" is just colloquial, a friendly informality. The other use is OK, but a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really that difficult to understand.  What brings a person to a place could also be a condition, or an event.  For example, my ailment brings me here to the clinic; or your birthday brings me here to your party.  Hence, it is perfectly correct to ask "so what brings you here?" in the present tense, in a similar way to asking "what is the purpose of your presence?" alluding to a situation, a condition or an event that could explain the presence of an individual.

Answer (score 0):

'What brings you here?' is a polite way of saying 'why are you here, right now? And as commenters noted 'why are you here?' is a bit rude, confrontational, whereas wording it 'what brings you here?' feels more like an invitation to answer, rather than a demand.

Whereas 'what has brought you here?' has 2 possible kinds of answer:

- I came by bus

Or

- 'Well, first I studied anatomy at Kings. Then I worked in a pharmacy, fell in love, had two children, got divorced, and now I'm looking to buy a packet of peanuts to eat while watching a movie'.

In other words, you risk getting the full and unabridged story of the process, when you ask like this.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What+brings+you+here%3f